# RRT nonholonomic constraints

Tags: geometry, algebraic-topology, optimization, random-graphs

Can some one please rephrase the visual meaning of the following claim

> key advantage of RRT over other algorithms (A*, Artificial Potential Field, etc.) is that it could impart the **nonholonomic constraints** to the tree nodes;

on 2:55 of [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JeEk_CWcRFI#t=2m55) video

What is [nonholonomic constraint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonholonomic_system#Constraints) in practice? I am looking for a 2D example of impediments to compare [A*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) or [Artificial Potential Field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_planning#Artificial_potential_fields) with [RRT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rapidly-exploring_random_tree).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Holonomic constraint is a constraint that is derived from the movement of some mechanical device/machine. For instance: a car car go left, right, but cannot turn sharply 90 degrees. If the car turns 90 degrees, it is following an arc (circle). This is what we call holonomic constraint. In case of your problem description, you are writing about pathfinding algorithms used in gaming. Here in case of non-holonomic movement you may imagine a car who can does not have to obey law of physics. A car which could go anywhere you want, turn to any side you want, with any degrees you want. You simply forget that a car has wheels which are limiting the range of your manouvers.

I hope it helped!

Answer (score 0):

The trajectory generated using a simple RRT cannot be followed by every robot/system. For example, lets consider a car-like robot lying on the origin (0,0) facing the Y-axis. Say the trajectory generated by RRT is a straight line segment connecting the origin to its goal on X-axis (lets say (5,0)). Now, the car cannot simply move horizontally right to reach (5,0). This is because its motion is bound by non-holonomic constraints which should be satisfied at every instant of its motion.

RRT being a sample-based algorithm has this excellent property of inculcating these non-holonomic constraints in its motion planning while sampling. Basically, to pick a new node in RRT, sampling is done from those points that have already satisfied the non-holonomic constraints. Hence, one can generate a trajectory that is feasible for non-holonomic class of robots which, most of the robots are.

I found [this](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/rrt-implementation-non-holonomic-robot-part-1-ankit-saini/) excellent blog explaining about RRT for non-holonomic robots.

PS: Non-holonomic systems/vehicles are those that are bound by the kinematic constraints that cannot be written in a closed geometric form. Instead, they are expressed as PDEs.

Comment: Someone gave (-1) to this answer. It will be great if he/she explains if the information is incorrect.